# SWT: How do you register KeyUp events when no Control have focus?

Tags: events, swt, onkeyup

Im am making an Java SWT program that is required to run on both Linux and Windows.

I use the following Code to listen for KeyUp events:

```
Control.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener() {

public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
 System.out.println("Event");

}
```

});

But this does not trigger when no control has focus.

Do anyone know of a place i can add a listener that acts as a Catch-all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have not been able to find a solution to this. I suspect none exist

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing this that I'm aware of is by placing a *filter* on the Display. Take note that multiple Shells may operate on one Display, so you should be careful!

```
shell.getDisplay().addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {
    public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try following method in Display class:

```
public void addListener ( int eventType, Listener listener )
```